# SQL Server string getting truncated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a column (`col1`) with `nvarchar(max)`.

I am trying to do

```
DECLARE @my_string NVARCHAR(max)
set @my_string = N'test'

UPDATE dbo.tab1 
SET col1 = @my_string + ISNULL(col1, N'')
```

no  luck , I have no idea why it is happening. @marc_s

The string value in `col1` getting truncated after 250 characters. This happening in both SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior you're reporting. How and why do you think your column gets truncated at 250 characters??

Comment: no triggers. The code is in a sql procedure.

Comment: Not to second guess you, but, you can run the exact code above and replicate this issue.  There's not something else buried in the stored proc you mention that could be truncating your value?  Not a buried cast or something?

Comment: Thanks Jocob. It's too big procedure. Some where down the line string was truncating to 250 chars.

Comment: SET TEXTSIZE could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - I'm not seeing this behavior you're reporting. How and why do you think your column gets truncated at 250 characters?? Are you using a tool to inspect the data that might be truncating the output??

You could check the length of the column:

```
SELECT col1, LEN(col1) FROM dbo.tab1
```

Is it really only 250 characters long???

Also: you're mixing `VARCHAR` (in `@my_string`) and `NVARCHAR` (`col1`) which can lead to messy results. Avoid this!

Next: if you want `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, you need to cast your other strings to that format.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @my_string NVARCHAR(200)
set @my_string = N'test'

UPDATE dbo.tab1 
SET col1 = CAST(@my_string AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ISNULL(col1, N'')
```

As I said - in my tests, I didn't need to do this - but maybe it works in your case?

Comment: I did select len(col1) from tab1  , it has 250 charecters. Also changed

Answer (score 3):

Go to menu - Query --> Query options -->  Results --> Text

There is an option `Maximun number of characters displayed in each column` and mine was defaulted to `256`.

Once I set this to `1000` the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you test in SSMS? If so, check in options `Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid` - `Maximum characters retrieved > Non XML data`. Is there a value 250 or similar?

Comment: NO. The value is 65530. I see only 250 from SSMS and from a java application(jdbc)

Comment: second guess: what is definition of the table? Is there some sort of check constraint? Like CHECK (DATALENGTH([col1]) <= 250)

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this because the max len of your data in col happens to be 250.

`ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )` will truncate the replacement_value to the length of check_expression, per:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql

Use COALESCE() instead, which avoids this risk.